# Is there a way to programmatically open a server-side file in a new tab?

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I'm running Jupyter notebook on a server and executing it from a client computer. In Rstudio server, one can programmably open a server-side file in a new tab via `file.show`. This is sometimes very convenient. For example, I have a script that processes a rather large image. Because of its size I don't want it to show directly in the output panel, rather I want to view it in a new tab. In Rstudio server I would normally do:

```
... image processing code ....
ggsave('temp.png')
file.show('temp.png')
```

This will automatically pop up the new image in a new tab once the script is finished.

Is it possible to do something similar in Jupyter?

I noticed that I could achieve this by clicking the image file in the built-in file browser, but I wonder if this could be programmed.

Similarly, is it possible to programmably open a webpage in a new tab like `browseURL` in Rstudio server? Note that `webbrowser.open(url)` doesn't quite do it because it tries to open a *local* browser, which in the server-client scenario will not open the new tab on the client side.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a link. Relative URLs will open in a new browser tab. Files are served relative to the directory containing the notebook you are currently working on.

In Python:

```
from IPython.display import display, HTML
display(HTML('<a href="temp.png">see image</a>'))
```

Opening new tabs programmatically often triggers pop-up blockers, but publishing a link that the user clicks should be reliable.